# “npx create-react-app appname” not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

When I run `npx create-react-app appname` I get the following error message:

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.0, which is behind the latest release (4.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/hat/Projects/youtube/react
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-react-app loll

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hat/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T06_53_20_858Z-debug.log
```

I then ran `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and got the following output:

```
up to date in 380ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

After running `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` command I ran `npx create-react-app appname` and I got the same error message as above.

This is what the error log located in `/Users/hat/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T06_53_20_858Z-debug.log` looks like:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/Users/hat/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/Users/hat/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'exec',
0 verbose cli   '--',
0 verbose cli   'create-react-app',
0 verbose cli   'loll'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.0.8
2 info using node@v15.2.1
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:file:/Users/hat/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:/Users/hat/Projects/youtube/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:/Users/hat/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/Users/hat/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 8ms
19 verbose npm-session ccfcf510fa3376be
20 timing npm:load Completed in 17ms
21 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 252ms (from cache)
22 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
23 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
24 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
25 timing command:exec Completed in 1728ms
26 verbose stack Error: command failed
26 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/hat/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
26 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:329:20)
26 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1055:16)
26 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:5)
27 verbose cwd /Users/hat/Projects/youtube
28 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
29 verbose argv "/Users/hat/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/bin/node" "/Users/hat/.nvm/versions/node/v15.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "create-react-app" "loll"
30 verbose node v15.2.1
31 verbose npm  v7.0.8
32 error code 1
33 error path /Users/hat/Projects/youtube
34 error command failed
35 error command sh -c create-react-app loll
36 verbose exit 1
```

I ran `npm cache clean --force` to clear the cache. The out after running this command was `npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.`

I'm running

- node version: v15.2.1
- npm version: 7.0.8
- npx version: 7.0.8
- OS: maOS CAtalina 10.15.7
- Im using vvm version 0.35.3 to manage my node versions

I also noticed that when I downgraded my node version to `v14.1.0`, `npm` and `npx` was automatically downgraded to 6.14.6. I then ran `npx create-react-app appname` and the command worked. I was able to create react app.

Is there a bug with node v15.2.1? It just doesn't make sence

Comment: try running 
npm init
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app myapp
in the same sequence

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem. Apparently, global installation of 'create-react-app' is no longer supported. So what I did was: '**npm install create-react-app**' instead of '**npm install -g create-react-app**'. Then npx create-react-app worked.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, because i have ran all the commands and was still getting different errors. But when i ran 'npm install create-react-app without adding the -g flag. 

Then npx create-react-app worked for me

Comment: Glad I could be of help :-)

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem.
I fixed it with

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

After that npx create-react-app worked.

Answer (score 1):

So,basically i just run this command::
**npm install -g create-react-app** instead of 'npm install create-react-app'.
Then:
**npx create-react-app app_name**
Goodluck!!