# React.js Not Updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

When I run the following command:
`npx create-react-app my-app`
I get this error:

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.1, which is behind the latest release (4.0.2).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

Even when I uninstall `create-react-app` or run the commands on the link provided, it keeps giving me this error. What should I do?

Comment: `npx create-react-app@latest ...` usually works for me.

Comment: Did you try upgrading from `4.01` to `4.0.2`?

Comment: I mean from `4.0.1` to `4.0.2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“npx create-react-app appname” not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963908/npx-create-react-app-appname-not-working)